# What does '+variable+' mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What does this: '+variable+' mean?

I use jQuery append method to add some DOM element:

```
$('#story_pages').append('<div><button value="'+window_value+'" onclick= "reload_to_canvas(this.value)" ><img id="w'+window_value+'", src=white_data_URL, width="100px", height="100px"/> </button></div>');
```

Actually, I don't why this works... 
If I just write

```
value= window_value 
img id= w+window_value
```

,and use the selector
    **$('#(w+window_value)')** 
to find the element. It must fail. 

What is this operator? '+variable+'

And why should we use the weird notation "'+variable+'"?

When should we use this notation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is this operator? '+variable+'

That isn't an operator.

`'` ends a string literal

`+` is a concatenation operator.

`variable` is a string variable

`+` is another concatenation operator.

`'` starts a new string literal.

> And why should we use the weird notation `"'+variable+'"`?

The two string literals have `"` characters in their data.

The object is to construct this:

```
'<element attribute="value">'
```

When the value is a variable

```
var myValue = "value";
'<element attribute="' + value + '">'
```

Generating code from code by string concatenation always gives ugly code, which is relatively hard to maintain. I'd approach the problem with a more verbose approach:

```
var content = $("<div>");
var button = $("<button>");
button.val(window_value);
button.on('click', function() { reload_to_canvas(this.value); });
var img = $('<img>');
img.attr('id', 'w' + window_value);
img.attr('src', 'white_data_URL');
// width and height can be handled in CSS
button.append(img)
content.append(button)
$('#story_pages').append(content)
```

Comment: +1 for the alternative approach (which has added benefits, for example you can put in some extra conditionals easily, and you can use a closure for the click handler instead of something that can be "stringified")

Comment: @Quentin       Thanks. But why value=window_value can get the content of window_value? I still have to use concatenation operator to do this job?

Comment: "But why value=window_value can get the content of window_value?" — It can't, because then `window_value` would be some letters in a string literal and not a variable name. That's why you either have to concatenate the strings together, or use DOM.

Comment: @Quentin         I mean I only write <button value=window_value></button> value= window_value seems just like an assignment...
And you see no string literal here, why can't it work?

Comment: It's an HTML attribute value. If you have that then the value is "window_value" and not the contents of the variable `window_value`

Comment: Do you mean that if we want to give a attribute value, we should use
value/src/width or something like this: value="THE VALUE WE WANT TO ASSIGN"?
The quotation mark is needed? So it seems that value=window_value is a mistake?

Comment: Depending on the version of HTML and the characters in the value, the quote marks around an attribute value may be optional in HTML. It is generally considered best practise to always use them.

Comment: I got it. But do we have another approach to get the content of a variable instead of the variable NAME?

Comment: If we're talking about HTML now, then there are no variables. There are attributes and values. Attribute names can never contain characters that have a meaning that could be misinterpreted as "end of attribute" or "end of element" etc.

Comment: @Quentin     What does "end of attribute" and "end of element" mean?
Do you mean that if we give attribute a value, we shouldn't give it a variable to escape the variable contains this: > so that it would be misinterpreted?

Comment: If attribute names could have (for example) `>` in them, then they would end the attribute they were in. They can't have `>` in them, so that isn't a problem, so they don't need to be quoted. Attribute values can have `>` characters in them, and when they do, the values must be quoted. HTML has no concept of variables, so in this context you *can't* give it a variable because there is no such thing. When generating HTML from JavaScript you have to end up with something that is valid HTML, but you are concatenating JavaScript strings together to do so and you have to be careful about …

Comment: … the quote marks which may have special meaning in HTML or JS depending on where they are and if they are escaped or not. You also have to be careful that your JavaScript strings in variables (which might come from user data) have the appropriate escaping performed and that the generated HTML has the right quotes.

Comment: So if we want to change or give the attribute value, we need to use
these instruction?
var img = $('<img>');
img.attr('id', 'w' + window_value);
img.attr('src', 'white_data_URL');
to give the value directly instead of variable?

Comment: "we need to use these instruction" — No, but it is the safest method. "to give the value directly instead of variable" — There is nothing stopping you using variables,  `window_value` is a variable.

Comment: +1 just for your perseverance and help, and also a reasonable, helpful answer to a surprisingly unlikely question.

Answer (score 1):

This is constructing a string dynamically using data from a variable.

```
var x = "World";
var text = "Hello " + x + ", how are you?";
```

The literal part of the string can be enclosed by either single quotes or double quotes. Each does the exact same thing, but if the string itself also contains quotes, one of the two is more convenient.

```
var text = 'Hello, "' + x + '", how are you?'; // double quotes inside
var phrase = "Hello, '" + x + "', how are you?";  // single quotes inside
```

Quotes needs to matched. Syntax highlighting (like here on Stackoverflow) makes this easier.

If you need both kinds of quotes inside of the string, you have to escape one of them with a backslash.

```
var lotsOfQuotes = ' "Gosh, O\'Neill, what have you done", he said. ';
```

Comment: you have syntax errors with a misplaced comma: '" + x +, "'

Comment: @popnoodles: Oops, thanks. Hopefully fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

That means that a string is concatenated with a variable.